# Oracle alertlog with WARNING: too many parse errors

Tags: oracle, alerts, parse

The SQLID is not available. Any ideas on how to find the source of the problem?

```
9913 WARNING: too many parse errors, count=414884 SQL hash=0x896ff002
9914 PARSE ERROR: ospid=24108, error=6550 for statement:
9915 2021-08-24T11:01:17.843825+02:00
9916 begin work
9917 Additional information: hd=0x24c179460 phd=0x24c17a888 flg=0x28 cisid=222       sid=222 ciuid=222 uid=222 sqlid=6jknqnu4qzw02
9918 ...Current username=SCHEMA_NAME
9919 ...Application: xxxx.exe Action:
9920 2021-08-24T11:03:07.555279+02:00
```

Answer (score 3):

The sql_id is `6jknqnu4qzw02`
It's telling you the bad SQL is coming from

```
Current username=SCHEMA_NAME
Application: xxxx.exe Action:
```

The SQL is:

```
begin work
```

As a side note, I recommend you add basic instrumentation to your application to set the `action` so you can easily link calls on the DB to a section of your application. You can use `dbms_application_info` explicitly but usually there's an argument built into the driver you are using to talk to the DB. e.g. in ODP.net this is just the ActionName member of the OracleConnection.

Answer (score 0):

We found the sessions with the ospid(=24108) from the alterlog and did a session trace.

```
--show Session details
Set lines 500
Set pages 500

select
       substr(a.spid,1,9) pid,
       substr(b.sid,1,5) sid,
       substr(b.serial#,1,5) ser#,
       substr(b.machine,1,15) box,
       substr(b.username,1,10) username,
--       b.server,
       substr(b.osuser,1,8) os_user,
       substr(b.program,1,30) program
from v$session b, v$process a
where
b.paddr = a.addr
and spid = 24108
and type='USER'
order by spid; 

-- Activate tracing
EXEC DBMS_SYSTEM.set_sql_trace_in_session(<SID>,<SERIAL#>, true );
EXEC DBMS_SYSTEM.set_ev(<SID>,<SERIAL>,10046,12,'');

-- Show trace path
select p.tracefile from v$process p, v$session s where p.addr=s.paddr and s.sid='SID01';
 
-- Stop Tracing
EXEC DBMS_SYSTEM.set_sql_trace_in_session(<SID>,<SERIAL>,false );
```

Not much new Information, but we could identified sql statements before and after the parse errors.

Answer (score 0):

This error looks similar in this DOC ID : 2649163.1